# how to save spark data frame to excel format?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-excel

I would like to save a Spark DataFrame into Excel.

I have done it for csv by saving csv file in each node and appending it in the server using the DataBricks spark-csv library.

I Don't know how to do it for Excel. Somebody please suggest and idea.

Comment: Why do you need to output a Excel file ? Spark is for big data processing. If you intend to open your output file with Excel, it is not big data anymore. So you can convert you csv file to excel file without Spark. Apache POI on single node should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datasource for the HadoopOffice library in Spark:
https://github.com/zuinnote/hadoopoffice

However, if the data volume to store is very large then it does not make so much sense, because Excel itself has issues to process large data files.

Answer (score 0):

```
%sh pip install XlsxWriter

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

import shutil, sys ,os
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter


df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 'foo'), # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
        (2, 'bar'),
      (3, 'bar1'),
      (4, 'bar2'),
    ],
    ['id', 'txt'] # add your columns label here
    )

    adls_path="/dbfs/mnt/"
       pd_df=df.toPandas()
       pd_df.to_excel('test.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
       shutil.move('test.xlsx', adls_path)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.